# Cronjob doesn't work when given a specific time

Tags: python, cron

I wanted to use crontab to set up a reoccurring script. I want it to run a python script everyday at 23:59, this is what I use:

```
59 23 * * * python /var/www/script.py
```

This doesn't seem to work. The script works fine when I run it standalone, but it doesn't get activated at 2359.

I tried something else as well:

```
*/1 * * * * python /var/www/script.py
```

This is would be a cron to run that same script once every minute. This works fine, it gets called every minute and all is good

Is there a reason why setting a specific time of day does not work, but setting it to go off every minute does?

Comment: What does happen. Does it not run or does it run at the wrong time. Are you running on a system or on a local computer? Are you sure that it is not shut down for the night? I once had a system that I thought ran 24/7 that was being shut down after everyone went home.

Comment: its on my linux box which I get into via SSH. my connection via ssh was still alive when the time of the cron was meant to go off so I'm sure that the box was alive

Comment: when the time hits, nothing happens. it does not run at all. if it ran  it would have inserted some rows into a mysql db I have, but there are no traces of new rows in there. so im pretty sure nothing actually happened - at least, the end results of what was meant to happen did not occur

Comment: Does the script print or log anything? Add a `>> /tmp/script.log 2>&1` after `/var/www/script.py`.

Comment: so i changed it to:
30 02 * * * python /var/www/script.py >> /tmp/script.log 2>&1

waited until 2:30am, went to try to find the log file and can't find it anywhere. safe assumption that cron didnt run when it hit 230?

Comment: Sounds like it, or there was some other error. Try adding path to `python`, e.g. `/usr/bin/python`. Run `which python` to see where the binary lives. Also check if you have `/var/log/cron` and see if `/var/log/syslog` have any information (my cron logs to syslog).

Comment: wow ok this is a big file. not sure how to interpret anything in here, but nothing happened at 2:30. the closest thing in time is:

`Mar 13 02:25:01 localhost CRON[8572]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`

what do you mean by adding path to python?

Comment: Somtimes the time is set for a different time zone. For example, I had a system that was set to PST when I was in the EST time zone. Another system that I was on used UTC instead of the local time zone.

Comment: yeah that was actually the first thing i checked. double checked the current time on the server and its set to the same timezone as me

Comment: Make the script executable, make sure line 1 is #! to the correct python and try to run it directly.  Make sure that the $PATH used by the cron job can see python.

Comment: yep I just checked to make sure all of those things are in place and it still doesnt run

Comment: how do user accounts factor into the running of cronjobs? do I assign them to particular users? does that user have to be logged in for the cron to run?

Comment: A cron job runs as the user whose crontab triggered the run and should be in his home directory unless the script being run has a cd command. Create an executable bash script which contains echo commands or which touches and/or removes files as well as calling your python script and see if anything gets done.  Try to "cat 'abcd'> dummy.txt" as well as the python and another one after the python script has been called.

Comment: Another question to check is the crontab on the server or your local platform? If it is on the local platform, then you may not be connected to the server at the time specified.

Answer (score 0):

A cron job runs as the user whose crontab triggered the run and should be in his home directory unless the script being run has a cd command. Create an executable bash script which contains echo commands or which touches and/or removes files as well as calling your python script and see if anything gets done. Try to "cat 'abcd'> dummy.txt" as well as the python and another one after the python script has been called. What user is runningt the crontab -e command.?

Are you getting any mail responses?

Answer (score 0):

The cron processes were working regularly every hour until I gave them a specific time.

first check if `cron` is running properly

```
sudo service cron status
```

if it failed, and you see something like:

> Active: failed ...
> ...
> /usr/sbin/cron[17912]: (CRON) DEATH (can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be XXXXX: Resource temporarily unavailable)

According to [the link here](https://www.bigbrus.com/2015/12/15/cron-death-cant-lock-varruncrond-pid-otherpid-may-be/) you need to kill the process and start it again.

to kill the process simply you can run:

```
sudo kill -9 $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
```

and start the service again:

```
sudo service cron start
```

finally, check whether it is running:

```
sudo service cron status
```

to read the reason behind, take a look at [the link](https://www.bigbrus.com/2015/12/15/cron-death-cant-lock-varruncrond-pid-otherpid-may-be/)